# Angular5 - karma/jasmine tests are failing on adding additional test

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I have lot of tests in my project which are running fine but as soon as I add one more test in a file it starts breaking without giving much information about the issue.
Here is what the error looks like:

```
{
"message": "An error was thrown in afterAll\nExpected false to be truthy.\n    
at http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/src/app/views/transfer-order-balance/transfer-order-balance/transfer-order-balance.component.spec.ts:292:47\n    
at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:391:1)\n    
at ProxyZoneSpec.webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/proxy.js.ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/dist/proxy.js:129:1)\n    
at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:390:1)\nExpected false to be truthy.\n    
at http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/src/app/views/transfer-order-balance/transfer-order-balance/transfer-order-balance.component.spec.ts:292:47\n    
at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:391:1)\n    
at ProxyZoneSpec.webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/proxy.js.ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/dist/proxy.js:129:1)\n    
at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:390:1)\nExpected true to be falsy.\n    
at http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/src/app/views/transfer-order-balance/transfer-order-balance/transfer-order-balance.component.spec.ts:291:73\n    
at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:391:1)\n    
at ProxyZoneSpec.webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/proxy.js.ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/dist/proxy.js:129:1)\n    
at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:390:1)\nExpected false to be truthy.\n    
at http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/src/app/views/transfer-order-balance/transfer-order-balance/transfer-order-balance.component.spec.ts:292:47\n    
at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:391:1)\n    
at ProxyZoneSpec.webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/proxy.js.ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/dist/proxy.js:129:1)\n    
at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:390:1)"
```

My test looks like below:

```
it('should display provided error message', () => {
component.message = 'Error message sent from other component';
fixture.detectChanges();
const errorElement: HTMLElement = fixture.nativeElement;
const errorMessage = errorElement.querySelector('p');
expect(errorMessage.textContent).toContain(component.message);
});
```

if i add similar test again with different message it fails to execute on PhantomJS but works fine on Chrome.

My package.json looks like below

```
 {
  "name": "@coreuipro/angular",
  "version": "1.0.8",
  "description": "Bootstrap 4 Admin Template",
  "author": "Łukasz Holeczek",
  "homepage": "http://coreui.io/pro/",
  "copyright": "Copyright 2017 creativeLabs Łukasz Holeczek",
  "license": "http://coreui.io/pro/license/",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "1.0.0-beta.2",
    "@angular/animations": "5.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "5.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "5.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "5.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "5.2.0",
    "@angular/upgrade": "5.2.0",
    "angular-calendar": "0.23.2",
    "angular-webstorage-service": "^1.0.2",
    "angular2-datatable": "0.6.0",
    "angular2-ladda": "1.2.3",
    "angular2-text-mask": "8.0.4",
    "angular2-toaster": "4.0.1",
    "bootstrap": "4.0.0-beta.3",
    "brace": "0.11.0",
    "chart.js": "2.7.1",
    "codemirror": "5.33.0",
    "core-js": "2.5.3",
    "dragula": "3.7.2",
    "flag-icon-css": "2.9.0",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "keycloak-angular": "^1.2.5",
    "keycloak-js": "^3.4.3",
    "lodash": "^4.17.5",
    "moment": "2.20.1",
    "ng-multiselect-dropdown": "^0.1.6",
    "ng-select": "1.0.0-rc.3",
    "ng2-ace-editor": "0.3.4",
    "ng2-charts": "1.6.0",
    "ng2-dragula": "1.5.0",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "2.0.0-rc.0",
    "ngx-pagination": "^3.1.1",
    "ngx-quill": "2.0.4",
    "rxjs": "5.5.6",
    "simple-line-icons": "^2.4.1",
    "spinkit": "1.2.5",
    "ts-helpers": "1.1.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.29"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.7.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "5.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.8.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "9.3.0",
    "codelyzer": "4.0.2",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.2.1",
    "karma": "2.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "1.3.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "0.2.2",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.4",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.16",
    "protractor": "5.2.2",
    "ts-node": "4.1.0",
    "tslint": "5.9.1",
    "typescript": "2.5.3"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I've seen issues similar to this happen in cases where you have tests that run asynchronously but outside of an Async zone. They don't always fail consistently which can make them very difficult to debug. I would suggest looking at any test that might be running asynchronously and making sure they are setup properly to handle that.

Comment: ok let me try if I can find the issue by isolating the asynchronous tests..